# msi uninstall failure with action:null and incorrect reference count

Tags: wix, windows-installer, nullreferenceexception

I'm new to Wix and having some problems with the installers.
I've installed some version on this computer , and changed the DLLs on System32 to new ones. once I've installed another version of the installer - the DLL's stayed the same as the one's I've changed , instead of being updated.

I looked at the logs :

```
    MSI (s) (EC:8C) [13:33:53:522]: Component: myDll.dll_x86; Installed: Local;       Request: Absent;   Action: Null
    MSI (s) (EC:8C) [13:33:53:522]: Component: myDll2k.dll_x86; Installed: Local;   Request:   Absent;   Action: Null
```

how come action is null?
someone told me it might be a problem with the reference count
so:

1. where can I find and see the reference count?
2. how can I fix this problem?
3. on another computer- all is being updated succeesfully..it's only at this one

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer best prctices say that components being installed to System32 should be permanent.  So however you  got here, it's functioning as it should.